# Newton’s second law in differentiation question

Tags: differential-forms

Any help would be massively appreciated

A vehicle of mass m=1000kg is brought to rest by a force F given by 
$$F=(0.5+4x)10^3  N$$
Where $x $is distance in metres.
Given that according time I the Second Newtons law $$F=m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$ find an expression for $x$ in terms of $t$.

Comment: $t$ here is time ?

Comment: Yes t  is the time

Answer (score 2):

Solve the differential equation

$$x''(t)-40x(t)=5.$$

Comment: How is this as the bracket was multiplied by 10^3 , not 10 ??